# Upload file in jsp

Tags: java, servlets

i am trying to upload file using this code :

```
    package controle;
    @WebServlet("/upload")
    @MultipartConfig
    public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String id;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    uploadFile(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    id = (String) request.getAttribute("id");
    uploadFile(request, response);
}

private void uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        String name = part.getName();
        InputStream is = request.getPart(name).getInputStream();
        String fileName = getUploadedFileName(part);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                "//C:/Users/achraf/workspace19/guidepro/WebContent/WEB-INF/imagesapp/profileapp"
                        + fileName);
        int data = 0;
        while ((data = is.read()) != -1) {
            fos.write(data);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
        response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
    }
}

private String getFormat(String fileName) {
    String format = "none";
    int index = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (index > 0) {
        format = fileName.substring(index + 1);
        format = format.toLowerCase();
    }
    return format;
}

private String getUploadedFileName(Part p) {
    String file = "", header = "Content-Disposition";
    String[] strArray = p.getHeader(header).split(";");
    for (String split : strArray) {
        if (split.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            file = split.substring(split.indexOf('=') + 1);
            file = file.trim().replace("\"", "");
            System.out.println("File name : " + file);
        }
    }
    return file;
}
```

}

but when irun my application i get this error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\achraf\workspace19\guidepro\WebContent\WEB-INF\imagesapp\profileapp (Accès refusé)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    controle.FileUploadServlet.uploadFile(FileUploadServlet.java:45)
    controle.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

what went wrong????

Comment: It seems that `profileapp` can't be found.

Comment: @M.Sharma still the same problem

Comment: Read my answer and see if it fits your problem. Then, give-me a feedback if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a folder by the name imagesapp under the WEB-INF and as you have

```
//C:/Users/achraf/workspace19/guidepro/WebContent/WEB-INF/imagesapp/profileapp"
```

which means it will append the `fileName` to `profileapp` and store it in `imagesapp`.But if you are assuming that the file will be kept under profileapp then just put a slash atfer it like this

```
C:/Users/achraf/workspace19/guidepro/WebContent/WEB-INF/imagesapp/profileapp/"
```

Comment: still the same  problem

Comment: go to the profileapp folder copy the path from the explorer and path it in your code and see

Comment: sorry but i don't undrestand what do you mean by 'path it inyour code'

Comment: Can you try writing the file in some other place except c:/ drive then you can get a idea whether it is a permission issue or code issue

Comment: it's not a permission issue because i uploaded in this folder in other applications and it works

Comment: paste C:/Users/achraf/workspace19/guidepro/WebContent/WEB-INF/imagesapp/profileapp in your  windows explorer it will say you whether the path is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

In uploadFile method:

```
    String name = part.getName();
    InputStream is = request.getPart(name).getInputStream();
```

You already has the part to get the input stream and are using getPart(name) to get the same instance part above.

I will not recommend to get the input stream to write after to a file with some output stream.
Instead if it do the following:

```
    String fileName = part.getHeader("content-disposition").replaceAll(".+filename=\"(.+)\"", "$1");
    String fileFormat = fileName.replaceAll(".+[.](.+)$", "$1");
    part.write("//C:/Users/achraf/workspace19/guidepro/WebContent/WEB-INF/imagesapp/profileapp/" + filename);
```

note here:

```
    "//C:/Users/achraf/workspace19/guidepro/WebContent/WEB-INF/imagesapp/profileapp"
           + fileName
```

is what you did. The final / is missing in profileapp.

The message error throws:

```
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\achraf\workspace19\guidepro\WebContent\WEB-INF\imagesapp\profileapp
```

profileapp is a folder. The message shows that your method return an empty string defined as "" at the begin of the method. If your method returns "SOME_STRING", you will see the following message error if the folder imagesapp doesn't exists:

```
      java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\achraf\workspace19\guidepro\WebContent\WEB-INF\imagesapp\profileappSOME_STRING
```

Otherwise you will create the profileappSOME_STRING file inside imagesapp folder.

If your profileapp folder doesn't exists, you would create the file profileapp inside imagesapp folder without exception. Not that you had an Access refuse. You are trying to write the content in a folder as a file.